# sending json huge data via body post is a good approach from frontend anchor link?

Tags: java, json, servlets

In frontend, I have a link named as `click here to download excel`, currently after clicking the link, its hitting to Java servlet Backend POST call. Currently I am sending a API url in json data in Body post, and from servlet I am hitting Rest API url.. I am wondering, instead of sending API Url via body post, what if I directly send JSON response data of API url to the servlet? (assume data could be huge).

Which is better approach?

Comment: What exactly are you posting? I don't understand what you mean by "directly send JSON response data of API url to the servlet". Your response should be a file stream for an excel file, not json

Comment: @cricket_007 In backend, iam creating excel sheet using some Java API, so for that I need some input data which is nothing but API Data response. so my doubt is: Currently iam sending API url via body post and then hitting API using Java, using api response data to build excel sheet.  What if I directly send API response data to servlet via Body post instead of API url?

Comment: If you have a "what if" question, it seems like you didn't at least try it yet

Comment: @cricket_007 Its not that I cannot try, I came here to find out which is best approach? Is that good sending large json data via body post? or instead I can get the same json data by sending API url via body post and then hit it in the servlet code to get that huge json data.. So, got my query?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "large" or "huge". Several megabytes of text? How else would you send it? Not via a URL parameter. Maybe a websocket

Comment: The fact of the matter is regardless of what API endpoints you hit, the data needs to get back to the client... And calling an HTTP request within the API to itself seems like a bad approach in general

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using ANgularJS with Java, when anchor link is clicked, it goes to java servlet

Comment: I'm not sure why the front-end language matters, but okay... What about it?